# Why did they change Harry Potter's wand From the first and second movie to the third and so on?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, wandlore

[image]

In the first Harry Potter movie and the second they get Harry Potter's wand wrong. The real one is looking like the wood of a tree but you can see it in the troll's nose and when Tom Riddle is holding it.

**Why did they change Harry Potter's wand from the first and second movie to the third and so on?**

[image]

Comment: Cause the one from the first movie got stuck up a troll's nose, the second got soaked in water, blood, and basilisk venom, the third had a traumatic experience and had to go to St. mungo's, (help me out here, guys!)...

Comment: Or it was just all a scam by Ollivander

Comment: You should not spam in caps when you are asking people for help, it is rude and disrespectful.

Comment: @CHEESE I believe that true answer lies in that Daniel Ratcliff stole first one so he can sell it at black Harry Potter market to buy himself truck full of cheetos. Second one had the same faith as he was not hooked on cheetos and couldn't live without them

Comment: You might want to slow down on the ranty, trivial questions. They aren't going to make a good first impression.

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic Definitely

Comment: Related. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133632/54605

Answer (score 20, accepted):

JK Rowling did do a televised conversation with Daniel Radcliffe where this matter came up in passing and Dan Radcliffe had this to say:

> It changed after the second film. It's a different wand I've got now and, um, 'cause in Alfonso's words he said that he thought the other wand looked too smooth and like it was from Ikea.
>
> [The interview is on YouTube at the moment, but I can't guarantee this link will work for ever.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BdVHWz1DPU) (Go to about 47:00)

Alfonso, by the way, is Alfonso Cuarón, the director of the third film, who made a lot of visual changes on taking over the reins (*Prisoner of Azkaban* was the first and only Harry Potter film he directed). So it was a simple aesthetic decision from the director.

Comment: Alfonso Cuaron wanted to develop the individuality of the wands and apparently allowed the trio at least to choose theirs from a selection. Characters like McGonagall and Malfoy kept theirs, but most changed.