# Did Tom Riddle and Voldemort have the same wand?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, adaptation-comparison, continuity

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133626/54605) caused me to think of another question.

The books/movies establish that Voldemort (as well as Harry) has a wand with the incredibly rare Phoenix feather as the core. Voldemort's wand is also depicted looking like a creepy bone type design (made of yew) to match his "evilness" which was made by Ollivander (at least in the movies)

[image]

Is this the same wand that was given to Riddle before his first year at Hogwarts? If not, what kind was it? It would seem odd that he would get such a wand designed like that as a child.

Comment: basically, the movie  guys are stupid

Comment: FWIW I read somewhere on here that you can only get one wand.  I read something about this when others were discussing about Hagrid's wand being broken, which is the sign you are banned from hogwarts/magic-world. The speculation was that Hagrid COULD NOT get another wand...  `Maybe this has to do with the fact Voldemort had 7 souls?`

Comment: @Himarm - if they are so stupid, how come they made so much $$$? :)

Comment: @XaolingBao: that's probably false, see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24371/4918

Comment: Ron eventually got a new wand after his was broken

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry I'm not that knowledgeable in this field, I just was going by what I had read :).

Comment: Is it that odd?  Look at kids who try to be counter-culture and adopt goth stylings or wear t-shirts from metal bands so they seem more bad-ass.  I'd expect if a kid had a wand that looked all death-y and skull-y at least some other kids would think it was pretty awesome.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Oh I don't know about that. Maybe you are thinking of kids now, I don't know, but decades ago I wore Metallica t-shirts. I don't wear them much now though I still listen to the music (even though disillusioned with them as a band for some years now) as it helps me a lot; even so I had around 150 of them when I stopped collecting them. But I most certainly didn't do it to 'be cool' or anything like that. Neither did I do it to be 'counter culture'. True I was always something of a non-conformist and 'rebel' (loosely defined) but not as you describe it. Maybe 'some' but not all?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To I understand that your comment is likely meant to be tongue in cheek but I can't help but reply anyway. They made so much money because Harry Potter is a loved story by many and it entertains. Probably most people don't notice the differences like the above even. I recall Richard here posted a picture in an answer and I couldn't even see from the picture what he was describing (my vision is poor). But of course they know how to entertain those who don't care about canon. Probably some who do care and care a lot about canon are entertained.

Comment: @Pryftan - You don't think Tom Riddle, from even before Dumbledore met him felt like an outcast and a loner?  Also, regarding whether it's a wand for kid or not, wands weren't generally custom-made for kids, you go there and the wand-master matches you with an existing wand that fits. As far as "back then...." kids, even decades ago, would turn on their favorite bands, shows, etc. if they felt their secret treasure was becoming mainstream-popular. That's not a "today" observation.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I’m trying to remember the full context here; it was a while back, have far too much going on and dead tired. I don't know how the wand portion of your comment to me is relevant to my comment to you but as for the other? I was just saying that not everyone wears a shirt - for example - 'to be cool' (or as you put it 'badass' but I'd rather not think of myself as a donkey). I think what you're getting at with the wand is that you were making an analogy. I know the wands are custom made; I was just saying that not everyone has a style just to 'fit in'. (1/2)

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I wore the shirts because I was a fan; most in my school weren't and I couldn't have cared less then any more than I did now. I liked them and still do. They also saved my life many times over the years. It's not only about style. But I won't go further because I know this site will whine about supposedly OT comments and other such things. Bottom line is hopefully clear now anyway. Oh and as for Tom Riddle not fitting in? He definitely didn't but did he want to? I don't think he did. (2/2)

Comment: @Pryftan - I'm not saying that EVERYONE does. Why do you think that because you were a true believer and fan and you only wore the shirts because of some artistic musical purity that no other teenagers wore band shirts because they thought it was cool?  So, yes, Tom Riddle didn't want to fit in with the mainstream (or any stream) of kids at school..... which would be, I don't know, COUNTER to the popular CULTURE.  So how does that dispute my comment that even someone who is not a harbinger of death, as a teen, might like a bad-assed wand?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Hmm we're on a total different page here :) I also reread your original comment again and maybe I missed something before. You were trying to say it's like *some* kids do [whatever] to be cool or whatever word they want to use but *not all*. I definitely wasn't talking about wands though. I would argue that using something of a donkey for a wand is rather cruel but oh well ... That's just an aside and unrelated. I believe though that I’m correct in the reinterpretation? In either event since I’m not refuting the wand part I think that's all there is to it. Cheers.

Comment: @Pryftan - I was speaking to the idea, in the question, that a kid would not want a wand design that seemed a bit "dark," in my original comment, and was stating that it was not at all uncommon for kids to lean in the direction, not because they are evil, but because many have a desire to seem unconventional, rebellious, "bad," whatever.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Sure. But that's only some kids is my point. I believe I even noted that but maybe not. Hardly matters though and I know this site will be complaining loudly - if someone doesn't do it for it - so I’m just going to end it here by saying that yes you're right but not everyone is that way: I most certainly was not but I also wore metal shirts. Still do even. Not because it was 'cool' but because it's part of me and it was my saviour too. I agree that many kids do care about that. Far too many in fact. Cheers.

Comment: @Pryftan - Feel free to point out where I ever said that ***ALL*** kids are like that.  I've mentioned this before, so I don't know why you keep coming back to it.  It seems like a bit of a straw man you set up there. It doesn't matter if it's "only some," because we're talking about someone who was something of an outlier to start with, right?  It's enough that there is nothing unusual about a school aged kid being non-conformist or embracing a "dark" persona. Every school has those kids, every school has groups of them.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet You didn't! :) If I did not clarify this I meant to; I reread your comment (I have been extremely stressed and knackered, have had a lot of terrible losses in the past two years and that's only some of what's going on .. - so I totally missed it at first). I came back to it because why? I honestly don't know. It might be because at that point it hadn't fully registered you weren't suggesting all kids. So no there's nothing to worry about. And you're right indeed about that. Put another way: a complete misunderstanding, you're right and though I am right you already covered that.

Comment: Perfect wand for an orthopedic wizard. If Madam Pomphrey had such a wand, I wouldn't bat an eye.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## It's the "same" wand, just redesigned.

None of the movie wands were special-looking in the first two films. *Prisoner of Azkaban* introduced the personalized wands, and the trend remained throughout the subsequent films. Before that, all wands pretty much looked identical - a simple black or dark brown wooden stick. So that's why they look different - there was a redesign of nearly all the wands (out-of-universe).

As pointed out in [CreationEdge's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133633/54827), the wand used by young Tom Riddle is a simple, dark-colored wand. Just as Harry's wand is the "same wand" in all eight<sup>1</sup> films even though it looked different in the first two films, I would say that **it follows that Voldemort's bone-looking yew wand is the same wand seen being used by Tom Riddle in *Chamber of Secrets*. The reason it looks different is simply that it too was *redesigned*, just like Harry's was.**

We know that Voldemort's bone-looking wand is the same one he got from Ollivander. See [Au101's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133634/54827) for quotes from the book.

[image]
[image]

---

A possible in-universe explanation could be that, at some point after *Chamber of Secrets*, Voldemort either had a newer, more evil looking outer shell added to his wand (or had the core put into a new wooden shell). Lucius Malfoy's silver snake head was an [ornamental add on](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/23150/54827), so maybe Voldemort did something similar. :)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Yes, I know Harry's wand broke in *Deathly Hallows part 1* but it was mended (off screen) in *Deathly Hallows part 2*, so one could still say it's the wand he used in all *eight* movies. Also it's simpler that way. :)</sub>

Comment: In-universe, once Voldemort realized Expelliarmus was Harry's signature spell, he decided his own wand needed a more ergonomic grip.

Comment: Ah... there's a whole new question, @Kyralessa, is an ergonomic grip a defense against Expelliramus?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure whether you're asking about the books or the movies. You mentioned the books a bit in your question, but the tags seem movie-centric.

CreationEdge's answer is excellent as far as the movie goes, but in the books I really don't think there's any question that it's the same wand. When Voldemort discusses the Elder Wand with Snape in *Deathly Hallows* he says:

> 'It has not revealed the wonders it has promised. I feel no difference between this wand and the one I procured from Ollivander all those years ago.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.525 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 32, *The Elder Wand*

When Harry interviews Ollivander in Shell Cottage, he says:

> 'The Dark Lord,' said Ollivander, in hushed and frightened tones, 'had always been happy with the wand I made him - yew and phoenix feather, thirteen and a half inches - until he discovered the connection of the twin cores.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.401 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 24, *The Wandmaker*

Of course, the fact that Harry's wand and Voldemort's share a core comes up throughout the series and there's never any mention of him obtaining a second wand from Ollivander, indeed we see throughout the series that the wand chooses the wizard and wand and wizard learn from each other. The Elder Wand excepting, people do not usually trade wands in.

We know that Voldemort's yew wand was the one he was using by the time he came to kill Harry and I see no reason to believe that he acquired this wand some time after starting at Hogwarts with some other wand, in fact I see every reason to doubt it.

Comment: Someone else added the movie/props/continuity tags after I wrote the question. I suppose I was hoping the books and the movies might line up in this regard (he got a new wand later on). I know, a fools hope.  Do the books describe the wand as depicted in the movies at all (looks like bone)?

Comment: Well, it's important to remember that the movies got a huge visual revamp after 2, lots of people's wands changed, including Harry's. No, the wands in the books are really much more of your traditional wand - a long wooden stick, there's none of this hyper stylised design that you get in the films (idk if you can tell, but I much prefer the book's way ;) )

Comment: *people do not usually trade wands in* - that's not entirely clear.  We know of at least one example apart from the Elder Wand: Charlie Weasley bought himself a new wand and Ron got the hand-me-down.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ron's parents also bought him a new wand after his was snapped in CoS, prior to PoA.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the original nature of the question, which seemed to be referring to simply the physical design of the prop within the movie:

**No, he didn't have the same design**. When you see his in the *Chamber of Secrets* flashbacks where he's confronting a young Hagrid. It appears to be a simple, sleek black or dark brown wand, with a simple handle.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If the newer "bony" wand had the Phoenix feather core, what was this wand's make up? Reading the other answer, this seems to be in conflict of the books?

Comment: @iMerchant - Voldemort could have had the original core put in a different wand.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Apparently Voldemort turned out to be Yewish. Or converted to Yewdaism. I bet yew are getting tired of my puns and wand me to quit. So I will.

Comment: I was gonna comment but it turned into an answer. See my answer. :)

Comment: @iMerchant Thank you for providing me one of the biggest laughs I have had in a good while. Brilliant punning! (Esp good because in German the J is pronounced as a Y and when I think of Judaism I think of German)  As for the question you asked of course it was just a film redesign and nothing to do with the book. Yes it's contradictory to the book (and I imagine you know that by now).

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of evidence in the books that Voldemort never changed his wand once until he discovered the twin cores and the problems they were causing for him (see quotes above).
However, this very fact is a plot hole, because it is unclear how Voldemort could regain his old wand after being reinstated into a body in Book 4. There is a gap of 13 years in which we don't know what happened to this wand, although we can be sure it is the same one due to the Priori Incantatem scene (Voldemort's wand regurgitates the last spells cast from it shortly after his resurrection, and those spells include the murders of Harry's parents which obviously happened *before* his downfall).

There is a blog post about this interesting question right here: https://nerdpiphany.wordpress.com/2018/02/10/peeves-pets-voldemorts-wand/
To summarize that post: When Voldemort tried to kill baby Harry, the killing curse backfired, he lost his body and escaped to Albania. In Book 1, Voldemort says that during that time in hiding, "any spell that could have helped me would have required a wand", as in, he didn't *have* one - or a body to hold it with. So his wand must have fallen to the ground the moment Voldemort lost his body. How it got from there into Peter's possession 13 years later is an unexplained mystery. The blog post walks through several possible explanations and concludes that none of them make sense.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While this does answer the question it would be better to include the information into the answer itself through an [edit]. As I like linking it to let me just copy this here [What is a plot hole?](https://imgur.com/gallery/L7zDu)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include the information in that link in the answer itself? Thanks!

Comment: I could have sworn that Voldemort explains that Peter Pettigrew retrieved the wand for his master? Maybe not though?

Answer (score -1):

I had this thought that as the witch or wizard grows, their wand will change and come to reflect their personality so by the time they leave their school they will have a unique wand that lines up with them. This theory allows for Tom to have both styles of wands without any need for convoluted explainations.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up this theory that you could [edit] in?

Comment: It's certainly a solution for a story that would have a problem here. Unfortunately it's the rubbish film that is the problem. They're always a problem, the films are. Many problems in fact. You're right that the wands do mould to their owners and some are harder to win (e.g. Bella's Unyielding) but the wand style itself does not happen to change in the book. One could argue though that your answer would work round the idiocy of the film!

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the previous comment on the wand "shapeshifting" to adapt to the wizard. Remember that Wands are ALMOST a living thing, and are very much sentient.

I know there is no confirmation on this and its is a widely believed theory.

This would clear why some "evil looking" are even so. I mean I doubt Ollivander would make a wand so "scary looking" like Voldemort's. It would seem fit that as the wizards comes to their own personality, the wand changes just like it can change or keep its allegiance.

examples:

Harry's is very natural looking, the handle is basically a bare trunk. I believe this reflects harry natural persona. He doesn't fake it, he says it how it is, but he is also pretty new to the magical world, not extremely fancy or concerned with etiquette but more as raw power and abilities

Bellatrix's has a bent and twisted shape, the way of holding it is twisted, with a straight one she'd be pointing at anything but her target. This is a clear parallelism to her mind status, twisted, bent, unsettling.

Voldemort's is dead looking, it has lost color and its "lively look" this too reflects him.

Severus' wand is black, straight, with a clear handle and "blade" so to speak. Everything was pretty cut and dry with it. You could say the wand is scary looking, but it is also plain and simple so it also be a good guy's wand. Just like Snape, his personality is also cut and dry. He has a feeling and acts accordingly. Like his wand his nature (good or evil) is not truly discernible and as a skilled Occlumency Practicer this is very fitting.

Umbridge's wand is very fancy, very ornamented, but, not at all ergonomic, not comfortable.

Whereas Draco's remained like the original, I believe this could indicate that Draco hasn't settled into his personality yet, we can see in the deathly hallows, that he starts helping Harry, questioning his allegiances. I believe Draco is a very malleable guy who hasn't had the change to develop HIS personality, but rather borrowed from his father.

Also Lucius' replacement wand was very plain, just like if the wand had had no time to "feel" Lucius and shape accordingly.

THIS IS NOT CANON, I know, but it makes darn good sense!

Comment: I’m not the one who downvoted; I wish everyone who did would comment as to why esp for a new contributor. But whether or not it's a theory it's dead wrong. You do point it's not canon and that's basically a summary of the rubbish films though I still say it's more accurate than Peter Jackson's atrocious abuse of Tolkien's Legendarium but whatever to that. Even so the wand doesn't change shape. Yes it does choose the wizard and some wands are better matches for certain personalities, are harder to win over and wands to get more attached to their owners but shapeshifter? Not at all.

Comment: As for the personality part: on Pottermore that is actually talked about; maybe you could somehow integrate that into your answer? I don't know how or what it might do wrt the question but it can at least possibly complement the part about the personality you refer to.